# how to setup proprely a cmakefile to build an universal binary (macos M1, linux and windows) including SFML and TGUI llibraries

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, apple-m1

I'm working on a project where we need to use teh SFML and TGUI libraries, but now that we try to compile the TGUI lib with the CmakeFile, I get an error on my macbook M1 because TGUI uses a member of SFML called "auto_ptr" which has been deprecated.

```
/SFML/Audio/AudioDevice.cpp:128:10: error: no member named 'auto_ptr' in namespace 'std'
/SFML/Audio/AudioDevice.cpp:128:19: error: 'AudioDevice' does not refer to a value
/SFML/Audio/AudioDevice.cpp:130:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'device'
```

I tried to specify other compilers to see if it changes anything but it didn't really work.

Can someone tell what could be changed/added in my CMakeLists.txt file to make it work, and if you see other things that could be improved in it feel free to comment it !

The content of the CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(r-type VERSION 1.0)

# set flags
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)

# include dirs
include_directories("includes")
include_directories("includes/external")
include(FetchContent)

#installing SFML
FetchContent_Declare(
        SFML
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
        GIT_TAG 2.5.1
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

FetchContent_Declare(
        TGUI
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/texus/TGUI.git
        GIT_TAG v0.9.5
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(TGUI)

# install enet
message(STATUS "Checking for enet ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
if (NOT EXISTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes/external/enet.h)
    message(STATUS "Downloading external library: enet in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    file(DOWNLOAD
            https://github.com/zpl-c/enet/releases/latest/download/enet.h
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes/external/enet.h)
endif()

add_executable(
        r-type_client
        src/client/Main.cpp
        src/client/OtherFiles.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (r-type_client ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(
        r-type_client
        sfml-audio
        sfml-graphics
        tgui
)
```

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` has been removed in c++17, I suspect the first error caused the rest. Try changing to `std::unique_ptr`, if `auto_ptr` was being used correctly `unique_ptr` should be  a drop-in replacement. SFML have already fixed this in their [latest code](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/commit/bf92efe9a4035fee0258386173d53556aa196e49) but don't seem to have released it yet

Comment: The error comes from a file from the Library, changing it would not fix the issue on other computers trying to build my project 

Comment: SFML simply isn't compatible with c++17 or later, either use c++14 or use a more recent version of SFML

Comment: I'm using std::clamp in the core of my project, which is not supported in c++14 ‍ error: no member named 'clamp' in namespace 'std'

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this working :

Adding this line :

```
set_target_properties(sfml-audio PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 98 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES CXX_EXTENSIONS NO)
```

after the FetchContent SFML block sets the Makefile to compile SFML using c++98

see https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24313.0